# While training Mask RCNN using TensorFlow Object Detection API, what is the 'loss'?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am training for **Custom Object Detection** using **Mask RCNN** in **TensorFlow Object Detection**. Therefore, I am to predict the object instance mask along with the bounding box.

Pre-trained model : `mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco`

Following is a snapshot of my training.

> INFO:tensorflow:global step 4181: loss = 0.0031 (3.290 sec/step)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:global step 4181: loss = 0.0031 (3.290 sec/step)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:global step 4182: loss = 0.0030 (2.745 sec/step)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:global step 4182: loss = 0.0030 (2.745 sec/step)

**In this case, can you please tell me what is the loss here?**

My questions is not related to training loss and its variation w.r.t. the steps.

I am just unclear about what is meant by this loss while training a Mask RCNN? In a Mask RCNN, there are 3 parallel heads at the last layer,

- for detecting the class
- for predicting bounding box
- for predicting instance masks

**In such a case, what is loss?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss function of the Mask R-CNN paper combines a **weighted sum of 3 losses** (the 3 outputs): classification, localization and segmentation mask:

[image]

The classification and bounding-box (localization) losses are the same as in Faster R-CNN.

**What is added is a per-pixel sigmoid + binary loss for the mask**.
The mask branch generates a mask for each class, without competition among classes (so if you have 10 classes the mask branch predicts 10 masks). The loss being used is per-pixel sigmoid + binary loss.

If you want to dive in a little bit deeper into the mask loss, the paper states that "Multinomial vs. Independent Masks: Mask R-CNN decouples mask and class prediction: as the existing box
branch predicts the class label, we generate a mask for each
class without competition among classes (by a per-pixel sigmoid and a binary loss). In Table 2b, we compare this to
using a per-pixel softmax and a multinomial loss (as commonly used in FCN [30])."

you can see it in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf) at page number 6, table number 2.b ("Multinomial vs. Independent Masks").